# Wrapping React's setState function in ES8's async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since React's setState is asynchronous, would it be recommendable to wrap its call in an async/await function, so that anything afterwards that critically depends on a state variable, would always get the updated value?

Comment: setState provides you a callback that you can use to make changes that depend on the current state. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback/42038724#42038724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a possible implementation of async/await. For example, inside your react component:

```
setStateAsync(state) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.setState(state, resolve)
  });
}

async setStateAndDoSomethingRightAfter(state) {
    await this.setStateAsync({state})
    // now do something after
}
```

**But I'm not sure if it would be *recommendable*. There are lifecycle methods for a reason.**

I believe the "react" way of doing things is to put your code that's dependent on new state inside of `componentDidMount` / `componentWillUpdate` / `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: We can directly use `await this.setState({state})`. No need to create such wrapper functions like setStateAsync!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second parameter of `setState`, a callback. [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).
`this.setState({ key: val }, callBack)`