# Display the date selected in react-datetime picker

Tags: reactjs, datetime

I want to display the date and time selected by the user from date-time picker on my UI . My code is as follows-

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Datetime from 'react-datetime';

class Datetimepicker extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        moveaside: false,
        feed_items: [],
        newText: new Date(),
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    this.showValuee = this.showValuee.bind(this);
}
updateState(e) {
    const text = e.value;
    console.log("text", text);
    this.setState({ newText: text });
    this.showValuee();
}
showValuee() {
    console.log(this.state.newText);
}
render() {
    console.log(this.props.value);
    return (
        <Datetime className={this.props.show ? 'rdt' : 'hide'} onChange={this.updateState} defaultValue={this.state.newText} />
    )
 }
}
export default Datetimepicker;
```

---

'text' shows undefined value.I am importing this 'Datetimepicker' component in my parent component and the Datetime picker I am using is this - (https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime)

Comment: In react, `setState` is asynchronous. If you want to log the value, you will have to use the callback for setState. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038724/4374566

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of react date time picker you have used uses `onChange` function programmatically and does not relay the change `event` back to the user. Instead the parameter inside `onChange` is the moment date object itself.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datetime: ''
    }
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }
  updateState(date) {
    // This function gives you the moment object of date selected. 
    console.log(date);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Datetime onChange={this.updateState}/>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/arqex/react-datetime/master/css/react-datetime.css"/>

<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/arqex/react-datetime/master/dist/react-datetime.js"></script>
```

Something else you should look up is how to use `setState` callback. Because setState is asynchronous, you cannot use a function to log the state value.