# react router and setState clashing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is this save? will this.props.history push ignore setState since setState is async?

```
if (id) {
    this.props.history.push(`/edit/${data.id}`)

  this.setState({
    showMsg: 'saved'
  })
}
```

or I should do this?

```
if (id) {
  this.setState({
    showMsg: 'saved'
  }, ()=>this.props.history.push(`/edit/${data.id}`))
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [when to use setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback/42038724#42038724), Also your syntax for setState callback is incorrect in the second case

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: For the first one, since you are using history.push, it will unmount the current component to navigate tothe correct route and within that period if you call setState, it would give you an error saying `Attempting to call setState for an unmounted component`, So you need to make sure that you call setState and then once it is completed call history.push

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of `setState` method is a callback and it will not accept it as argument.

change this

```
  if (id) {
      this.setState({
        showMsg: 'saved'
      }, this.props.history.push(`/edit/${data.id}`))
    }
```

to this

```
if (id) {
  this.setState({
    showMsg: 'saved'
  },()=> this.props.history.push(`/edit/${data.id}`))
}
```

> Is this save?

Yes when you set a state and once its set; you get through callback. It will push to history after state was set.

Comment: I'm asking it is save for the first block of code, not the second one, I know second one make sense.

Comment: @YunyiChang, No it will not save since you are pushing history and in the meantime that component should have been unmounted.