# I am having an error while updating my states in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

While trying to update the state from a function and calling the function from `componentdidmount` lifecycle method, the state doesn't update.
But when I try to update the state by calling the function from inside the jsx, it does work. I dont know what is happening

```
//my state
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        activepage:'dashboard',
        language:[],
    }
}

//the function I am updating state from
getLanguage = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/language')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.language);
            this.setState({
                language:response.data.language
            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return error;
    });
}

//I am calling function from
componentDidMount(){
    this.getLanguage();
    console.log("state after updating",this.state) //displays an empty array
}
```

But when I call function `getLanguage` from inside the jsx it updates the state.

Comment: When you update `state`, it doesn't get updated immediately. You can use `setState` callback to see when the state is updated. 
See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604716/4089357

Comment: you check with react dev tool, instead of console, here, also

Comment: Thankyou.It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your function with es6 arrow function

```
.then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.language);
        this.setState({
            language:response.data.language
        })
    })
```

Comment: @MUsmanNadeem this doesn't make sense, if this is the issue, it shouldn't update in either case (but he said it does update through jsx).

Comment: It worked. I added a callback and it worked properly

Answer (score 0):

For `es6` you can use `arrow function`

```
getLanguage = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/language')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.language);
            this.setState({
                language:response.data.language
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return error;
        })
    );
}
```

For `es5` you can declare `this` out of scope `axios` function

```
function getLanguage() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/language')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data.language);
            self.setState({
                language:response.data.language
            })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return error;
        })
    );
}
```