# async in a function, wait for first function to finish before the next is fired

Tags: javascript

I am so used to using RXJS in Angular, I have not had the chance to learn vanilla JS async functions yet. With that being said, how would I modify the method below so that `this.onFilterButtonClicked()` is only fired once `this.setState()` is finished as an async function? Or is using async even the right thing to do here?

```
onResetFiltersButtonClicked() {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        selectedFunnelStatuses: []
    });
    this.onFilterButtonClicked();
}
```

Comment: setState has a callback you can use, more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: great that you recognized this as part of a react app right off the get go!