# Getting undefined when json fetch in react native

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

In my simplified code below I am able to pull data in JSON format but if I try to console log a specific key of the object, I get undefined.

I had thought I could use `this.state.profile.name` to display "Steven". 
Why is this coming up as `undefined` when I'm able to see the entire response? Thanks!

```
state = {
responseJSON: null,
};
callGraph = async token => {

const response = await fetch(
  `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name,email,about,picture`
);
const responseJSON = JSON.stringify(await response.json());

  this.setState({ 
    profile: responseJSON
  });

console.log("profile = " + this.state.profile);
};
```

this `console.log` output the following:

```
profile = {"id":"*******","name":"Steven *******","email":"steve@*******.com","picture":{"data":{"height":50,"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=*******&height=50&width=50&ext=1539943832&hash=AeQM2VfUBmdfOVJZ","width":50}}}
```

Comment: Also it should be state = { profile: null}. But I don’t think that will solve your issue.

Comment: Something else must be wrong in your code. Because if your console log git you this output, you should be able to log `this.state.profile.name` too

Answer (score 4):

`setState` is asynchronous.

In your code, you are trying to `console.log` before the state is updated.

You need to use the callback as the second argument of the `setState` function:

```
 this.setState({ 
    profile: responseJSON
  }, () => {
console.log("profile = " + this.state.profile);

});
```

Check [this post](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3) for more information or also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Answer (score 2):

setState is asynchronous. The answer of Kevin is completely right. However, you can also use this method to see the result immediately:

```
this.profile= responseJSON;
console.log("profile = " + this.profile);
```

You should also define it in the constructor like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.profile='';
   }
```

Also, in order to access the parameter of profile in your screen you need to use `this.profile`.

Comment: good point! And thank you for saying I was completely right ahah

Comment: So sorry guys, looks like my question was cut off a bit. I followed Kevin's original answer and I'm trying to output a parameter like name but get "undefined". 


`this.setState({ 
    profile: responseJSON
  }, () => {
    console.log("profile = " + this.state.profile.name);
  });`

Comment: @StevenSheffey: That is strange, how about my approach? dose it work?

Comment: @Reza Strange indeed, I will try your solution tonight and get back to you guys asap.