# ComponentDidMount react native state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My code:

```
   componentDidMount() {
       this.getEmail;
       console.log("checkpoint")
   }

   getEmail = () => {
       var email="something";
       this.setState({
           email: email,
       });
       console.log(this.state.email)
  }
  render() {
    return (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.text} onPress={this.getEmail}>email :{this.state.email}</Text>
          </View>
    );
  }
```

Console.logs :

```
//nothing happened?
checkpoint
(onPress Text into JSX)
this.state.email
something
```

So my function works well but ComponentDidMount doesn't execute getEmail, but if i press "email :" this load my state and all is fine.

I would like that ComponentDidMount execute my function

Comment: `this.getEmail()` and not `this.getEmail`

Comment: I don't understand why `getEmail` is an `async` function

Comment: nevermind it's in my code, you can call getEmail (onPress={this.getEmail} work well)

Comment: `this.getEmail()` and not `this.getEmail` in `componentDidMount` and your code is great :)

Comment: Ty, i didn't understood the difference, now yes, TY

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getEmail();
    console.log("checkpoint")
}
```

Of course, `onPress={this.getEmail}` is executed when you press the text, but that's because onPress event listener make `this.getEmail` into `this.getEmail()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change componentDidMount function:

```
componentDidMount() {
       this.getEmail();
       console.log("checkpoint")
   }
```

and tell me if it's what you looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `getEmail`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getEmail();  // () is added here
    console.log("checkpoint")
}
```

Also, you wrote:

```
getEmail = () => {
   var email="something";
   this.setState({
       email: email,
   });
   console.log(this.state.email)
}
```

which is wrong. `setState` is **asynchronous** and `this.state.email` might not be there when you log it (take a look on [When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)). To fix this you should write:

```
getEmail = () => {
   var email="something";
   this.setState({
       email: email,
   }, () => console.log(this.state.email));
}
```