# Ensuring React state has updated for game loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a version of Conway's Game of Life in React. The component's state contains the `grid` describing which of the cells is alive at the current time. In each game loop, the new `grid` is calculated and the state is updated with the next iteration.

It occurs to me that since `setState` is asynchronous, when repeatedly calling the `iterate` function with `setInterval`, I am not guaranteed to be using the current version of `grid` each time `iterate` runs.

Is there an alternative to using `setInterval` in React that would avoid any potential issues caused by `setState` being asynchronous?

Here are the relevant functions that describe the game loop:

```
  go = () => {
    const { tickInterval } = this.state;
    this.timerId = setInterval(this.iterate, 570 - tickInterval);
    this.setState({
      running: true,
    });
  };

  iterate = () => {
    const { grid, gridSize, ticks } = this.state;
    const nextGrid = getNextIteration(grid, gridSize);
    this.setState({
      grid: nextGrid,
      ticks: ticks + 1,
    });
  };
```

Comment: `setState` can take a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42038590/1813169) which executes *after* the new state has completely propagated.

Comment: With `this.timerId` coming from `setInterval`, I can easily stop the loop by calling `clearInterval`. Using callbacks, I guess the callback function would be using `setTimeout`? What would be the way to stop a loop consisting of callback functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set state based on a current state, it is wrong to directly rely on `this.state`, because it may be updated asynchronously. What you need to do is to pass a `function` to `setState` instead of an object:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  // updated state
}));
```

And in your case it would be something like:

```
iterate = () => {

  this.setState(state => {
    const { grid, gridSize, ticks } = state;
    const nextGrid = getNextIteration(grid, gridSize);
    return {
      grid: nextGrid,
      ticks: ticks + 1
    }
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

SetState is Asynchronous

```
this.setState({
    running: true,
});
```

To make it synchronously execute a method:

```
this.setState({
     value: true
}, function() {
    this.functionCall() 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the react official documentation, the `setState` api does take a callback in following format:

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

Here the first argument will be your modified `state` object and second argument would be callback function to be executed when `setState` has completed execution.

As per the official docs:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

You can have a look at official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to get more information on this.

Comment: If I understood the docs correctly, I don't actually need to use the callback, the first argument supplied to the `updater` function will use the most up-to-date version of `state`, so I think the answer from streletss is easier to implement.