# React: Batching state updates tied to event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' event listeners. Several of this same component render next to one another (or overlap) in the browser, so it's possible to fire a 'mouseover', 'mouseout' and then another 'mouseover' event in that order **(if you're hovering over from one element to the next)**.

The component sets state in all of those instances, but I'm wondering if there isn't a more efficient way of going about this, so as to avoid three state updates happening one after another.

Am I trying to unnecessarily optimize here or is this a valid concern? Here's an example of what I mean. In this case I'm just updating a count, but let's say I'm doing something more expensive like iterating over an array.

*(Disclaimer, I haven't used the new code insertion on here and I'm having trouble running this snippet).*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DummyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    someProp: 1
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.addEventListener('mouseover', this.handleEvent);
    this.addEventListener('mouseout', this.handleEvent);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeEventListener('mouseover', this.handleEvent);
    this.removeEventListener('mouseout', this.handleEvent);
  }
  
  handleEvent(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    this.setState({ someProp: this.state.someProp += 1 });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        {this.state.someProp}
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Comment: Is it necessary that the event get handled immediately?  If not, it seems like a good use case for debouncing the handling so that it doesn't happen more frequently than say 100ms: https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce ... downside is that the handler will wait at least that long before firing the first time.

Comment: @DanielBank There is some UI dependent on state updating, but you might be right. 100ms might be just enough of a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary that the event get handled immediately? If not, it seems like a good use case for debouncing the handler method so that it is not invoked more frequently than **X** milliseconds (e.g. 100ms).  The downside of this is that the handler will wait at least that long before firing the first time.

The Lodash library provides an implementation of [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce).

Below is how your code could be modified to use it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

class DummyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    someProp: 1
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.addEventListener('mouseover', this.debouncedHandleEvent);
    this.addEventListener('mouseout', this.debouncedHandleEvent);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeEventListener('mouseover', this.debouncedHandleEvent);
    this.removeEventListener('mouseout', this.debouncedHandleEvent);
  }

  handleEvent(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    this.setState({ someProp: this.state.someProp += 1 });
  };

  // Debounced handler with a wait time of 100ms
  debouncedHandleEvent = _.debounce(handleEvent, 100)

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        {this.state.someProp}
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```