# expect(received).toEqual(expected) - error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to run an unit test for React JS - using jest / enzyme.

The test is failing at the moment.Not really sure why, maybe i am not calling the expect(wrapper.find) correctly. Here is part of my test:

```
 File.test.js

   it('renders modal when open flag is true', () => {
 const props = { isOpen: true }; 
 const wrapper = mount(
 <div id="root">
  <Component {...props} />
</div>
);
 wrapper.update();
expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
 expect(wrapper.find('.loa-download-header').exists()).toEqual(true);
expect(wrapper.text()).toContain(' Please enter a password.');
 });
 });
```

Here is part of File.js Shows a piece of the code that I am trying to test as an example.

```
 render() {
return (
  <Modal

       <div title="Close Window" className="add-custom-field-close" onClick={() => {this.closeModal()}}><FontAwesome name='xbutton' className='fa-times' /></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='loa-download-header-wrapper'>
        <div className='loa-download-header'>
          Please enter a password.
          </div>
```

Error:  expect(received).toEqual(expected)

```
Expected value to equal:
  true
Received:
  false
```

Any corrections on the code would be extremely helpful Thanks

Comment: did you tried removing space before Please "expect(wrapper.text()).toContain(' Please enter a password.');"?

Comment: @MadTech the error is referring to this line : expect(wrapper.find('loa-download-header').exists()).toEqual(true); and I did remove the space - I still get an error

Comment: you can try to debig it `node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand` https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting

Comment: @ChotalaParesh does the code look right to you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent some time integrating your code into a sandbox. There are quite a few changes to your code, which I've listed below. I've also included some tests that have been filled in and some that are not. What you should do is spend some time familiarizing yourself with these changes so that you can fill in the rest of tests in `containers/LOAs/__tests__` **on your own**.

Even though I wrote an integrated test for the `LOAs` container, I encourage you to write a unit test for the smaller `components`, so that you can practice mocking `prop` functions, checking if they're being called, and making sure the component functions as expected. Even though it'll be redundant, it'll help you understand the flow, what to test, and how to test (for unit tests, you'll want to use the `shallowWrap` instead of the `mountWrap` function -- or don't use them and use the provided `shallow` and `mount` functions offered by `enzyme`... up to you).

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/p3ro0615nm

**Changes**:

- Created a [container](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) component that handles all `UI` and `state` changes
- Used `this.setState()` [callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback) to keep `state` and secondary actions synchronous. Just as important, this also reduces unwanted component flickering.
- Used [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) with the use a [ternary operator](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff)
- Used [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s `filter`, `map`, and `isEmpty` functions (they're convenient and I prefer them over native JS functions)
- Mocked 2 API calls (noticed that I've used `setTimeout`, as this **will** affect your tests). In the `fakeAPI.post` function, I added a fake password to check against, therefore, the supplied password must be **12345**!
- Added the ability to select and unselect LOAs. If desired, you can simplify all of that with checkboxes.
- Class `methods` start with `handle`, while passed down methods start with `on`.
- Broke down `components/LOAModal/LOAModal.js` into smaller/reuseable components to make it easier to read
- Added `PropType` checking to make sure props were consistent during initial declaration and across components.

**Notes**:

- A major part of testing is understanding what's happening behind the scenes, so take the time to read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html); and, if necessary, do smaller/simpler projects to help familiarize yourself with how React works.
- When testing, if you need to see the `DOM` as `enzyme` sees it, then you can `console.log(wrapper.debug());` inside of your `it` test.
- You can utilize `jest.useFakeTimers()` in the `beforeEach()` function and `jest.runAllTimers()` in the `afterEach()` function to simulate `setTimeout` functions without having to wait for real time to pass.
- **Very important**: Always include a `.catch()` after a `Promise` (an API call). If you don't `catch` your Promises, then it can crash your app.

Comment: thank you very much. I will definitely take a look what you have done. Do you offer tutoring ?

Comment: I do not. However, if you're willing to invest some time and a little bit of money, then I'd suggest investing in this online course: https://www.udemy.com/react-2nd-edition/