# Mocking SyntheticEvent handler for onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I need to write a test to simulate the click on a chevron for changing pages.  The function called when onClick occurs has a synthetic event handler as a parameter and I need some way to mock this event handler (or rewrite the code with the same functionality) . I currently get the error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Edit:  Everything is contained in setTimeout because the buttons won't render until several promises have been resolved

Here is the function code

```
handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.currentPage > 0) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
    });
  }
};
```

here is the code inside the render function

```
<Icon
  link
  href="#"
  onClick={this.handleClick}
 >
   chevron_left
 </Icon>
```

And finally my test code thus far

```
 test("Chevron left", done=>{
  Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
  const wrapper = shallow(
      <App/>
  );
  expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);

  setTimeout(()=>{
      wrapper.instance().state.currentPage = 1;
      wrapper.find("Icon").at(0).simulate("click");
      expect(wrapper.instance().state.currentPage).toEqual(0);
      done();
  },0)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need `e.preventDefault()` in the `handleClick` method (in this case). You can remove it and be fine.

However, in case you run into this issue where it's required (like `form` submissions or where you find that the page auto refreshes or you want to prevent a default action event), then just add a mocked `preventDefault` in the simulated `click` event:

```
wrapper.find("Icon").at(0).simulate("click", { preventDefault: () => null });
```

To ensure proper state changes, change your handleClick method to one of the below (since `setState` is asynchronous, utilizing its [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback) ensures values are accurate upon comparison):

Option 1 -- handleClick method:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState(prevState => {
     const nextPage =  prevState.currentPage - 1; // subtract 1 from current page

     return nextPage > 0 // if next page is greater than 0
       ? { currentPage: nextPage } // subtract 1
       : { null } // else do nothing

  })
}
```

Option 2 -- handleClick method:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
     currentPage: prevState.currentPage > 0 ? prevState.currentPage - 1 : 0 // if current page is greater than 0, subtract 1, else set it 0
  }))
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm testing someones code and was questioning if it was even necessary having it.  However your solution worked!

Comment: You bet. Also see updated answer for a better `handleClick` callback.