# How to get a particular div into fullscreen(full window size) in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fullscreen

I am making a Image viewer in ReactJs as I am newbie in this so I stuck at a point. actually I have to add a full screen option. when user click on any particular image the image is open and there is a option like next,prev,close,rotate and fullscreen(that is takes height and width of browser) so when user click on full screen that particular image will get the full window size and user still have option like rotate,next.close and prev. I searched for so many solution but nothing worked.

I tried so many things but it only does the fullscreen whole body but I want .center-image to be full screen with options as I said. This is the gallary modal component.

```
class GalleryModal extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
            rotation: 0
          };
          this.rotate = this.rotate.bind(this);
        }

        render() {
          const { rotation } = this.state;
          if (this.props.isOpen === false) {
            return null;
          }

          return (
            <div className="modal-overlay" name={this.props.name}>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <a href="#" className="button" onClick={() => this.rotate()}>
                  <i className="fas fa-sync-alt" />
                </a>
                <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.props.onPrev}>
                  <i className="fas fa-angle-left" />
                </a>
                <img
                  className="center_image"
                  id="image"
                  src={this.props.src}
                  style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)` }}
                />
                <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.props.onNext}>
                  <i className="fas fa-angle-right" />
                </a>
                <a
                  className="modal-close"
                  href="#"
                  onClick={this.props.onClick}
                >
                  <span className="fa fa-times" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
        rotate() {
          let newRotation = this.state.rotation + 90;
          if (newRotation >= 360) {
            newRotation = -360;
          }
          this.setState({
            rotation: newRotation
          });
        }
      }
```

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/f1pg4k7r/3/)

This is my code and I am confused how to add the fullscreen option and where to add it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use some `css` tricks, but I believe this is what you're looking to achieve. The image is centered and takes up the maximum amount of width that is available within the window; however, if you stretch the window, it'll adjust its width up until it hits its max width (not advised to stretch it beyond its max value, otherwise, you'll get pixelation).

I did simplify your code a bit by elevating `state` and class `methods` to a single `container`, as well as, used `setState()` [callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback) to manage `state` more efficiently and the [ternary operator](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff) (`cond ? true : false`) in replace of simple `if/else` conditional statements.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/zr5k7v0zp3

**containers/Gallery/Gallery.js**

```
import React from "react";
import GalleryImages from "../../components/GalleryImages/galleryImages";
import GalleryModal from "../../components/GalleryModal/galleryModal";

const imgUrls = [
  "https://source.unsplash.com/3Z70SDuYs5g/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/01vFmYAOqQ0/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/2Bjq3A7rGn4/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/t20pc32VbrU/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/pHANr-CpbYM/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/3PmwYw2uErY/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/uOi3lg8fGl4/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/CwkiN6_qpDI/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/9O1oQ9SzQZQ/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/E4944K_4SvI/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/-hI5dX2ObAs/800x600",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/vZlTg_McCDo/800x600"
];

export default class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imgIndex: 0,
      imgUrlLength: imgUrls.length,
      showModal: false,
      rotation: 0
    };

    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    this.nextClick = this.nextClick.bind(this);
    this.prevClick = this.prevClick.bind(this);
    this.rotateImage = this.rotateImage.bind(this);
  }

  openModal(index) {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true,
      imgIndex: index
    });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: false,
      imgIndex: 0,
      rotation: 0
    });
  }

  nextClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        imgIndex:
          prevState.imgIndex === prevState.imgUrlLength - 1
            ? 0
            : prevState.imgIndex + 1
      };
    });
  }

  prevClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        imgIndex:
          prevState.imgIndex === 0
            ? prevState.imgUrlLength - 1
            : prevState.imgIndex - 1
      };
    });
  }

  rotateImage() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        rotation: prevState.rotation + 90 <= 270 ? prevState.rotation + 90 : 0
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid gallery-container">
        <GalleryImages imgUrls={imgUrls} openModal={this.openModal} />
        <GalleryModal
          isOpen={this.state.showModal}
          onClick={this.closeModal}
          onNext={this.nextClick}
          onPrev={this.prevClick}
          rotateImage={this.rotateImage}
          rotation={this.state.rotation}
          src={imgUrls[this.state.imgIndex]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**components/GalleryImages/galleryImages.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const GalleryImages = ({ imgUrls, openModal }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      {imgUrls.map((url, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} className="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xl-2">
            <div className="gallery-card">
              <img
                key={index}
                className="gallery-thumbnail"
                src={url}
                alt={`Image number ${index + 1}`}
              />

              <span
                className="card-icon-open fa fa-expand"
                onClick={() => openModal(index)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

GalleryImages.propTypes = {
  imgUrls: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  openModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default GalleryImages;
```

**components/GalleryModal/galleryModal.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const GalleryModal = ({
  isOpen,
  onClick,
  onNext,
  onPrev,
  rotateImage,
  rotation,
  src
}) => {
  return isOpen ? (
    <div className="modal-overlay">
      <div className="modal-body">
        <div className="close-modal">
          <a className="modal-close" href="#" onClick={onClick}>
            <span className="fa fa-times" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="rotate-container">
          <a href="#" className="button" onClick={rotateImage}>
            <i style={{ fontSize: 44 }} className="fas fa-sync-alt" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="image-container">
          <div>
            <a href="#" className="button" onClick={onPrev}>
              <i className="fas fa-angle-left" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              src={src}
              style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`, width: "100%" }}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" className="button" onClick={onNext}>
              <i className="fas fa-angle-right" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

GalleryModal.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onNext: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onPrev: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rotateImage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rotation: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  src: PropTypes.string
};

export default GalleryModal;
```

**styles.css**

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.button {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #eee;
  margin: 5px;
}
.card-icon-open {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 45%;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0%, -400%);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.card-icon-open:focus,
.card-icon-open:hover {
  color: #111;
}
.close-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
}
.fullscreen {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #eee;
  z-index: 999;
}
.fullscreen:hover,
.fullscreen:focus,
.fullscreen:blur {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
.gallery-container {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.gallery-card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.gallery-thumbnail {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.gallery-thumbnail:focus ~ .card-icon-open,
.gallery-thumbnail:hover ~ .card-icon-open,
.gallery-thumbnail ~ .card-icon-open:focus,
.gallery-thumbnail ~ .card-icon-open:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.image-rotate {
  font-size: 44px;
}
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.75);
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  z-index: 11;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.modal-close {
  font-size: 44px;
  z-index: 99;
  color: #eee;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.modal-close:focus,
.modal-close:hover {
  color: red;
}
.rotate-container {
  font-size: 44px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Actually before seeing your solution I tried myself all thing is going well  but a error occurs like when I click on any image and rotate it and close it and after that if I opens other it takes the previous `rotation` value but it must be zero.  https://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/r0h7gv62/1/  This is what I tried when you click on full screen icon it will fullscreen the image . But I doesn't know from where the rotation error is arrised can you please tell me what I am doing wrong???? @MattCarlotta

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using css viewport units, setting a component to height: 100vh and width: 100vw will make it fullscreen. You then conditionally render the component based on when you want it to be fullscreen.

Comment: Basically I want the image `.center_image` to take full window size on click of that button .plz see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/f1pg4k7r/3/ ....  I stucked on it over a month so plz help .

Comment: Josh literally just gave you the solution to your problem @AyushSrivastava

Comment: I m really sorry @JasperLichte as I don't very much about reactJS  I am beginner I understand that if I give any element 100vh and 100vw it will take full screen (not window size) But I am stuck that how can I manage to get that particular div full browser height and width?

Comment: @AyushSrivastava I kinda fail to understand your question. Just add a className/id to your desired div and size it in your css file. Alternatively, assign a `style` prop to your div. Just like you'd do in vanilla JS really

Comment: @JasperLichte I tried myself what I understand from these answer all thing is going well but a error occurs like when I click on any image and rotate it and close it and after that if I opens other it takes the previous rotation value but it must be zero.This error is arrising after I edited all my code. see jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/r0h7gv62/1 This is what I tried when you click on full screen icon it will fullscreen the image . But I doesn't know from where the rotation error is arrised can you please tell me what I am doing wrong????

Comment: Now you are asking a completely different question. Please accept my answer if it was helpful and then open a new question for your new problem. Keeping one question about one problem helps other people with your original problem find this thread.

Comment: @JoshPittman can u please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746698/variable-is-not-taking-the-initial-value-of-a-variable-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Found this library which does exactly what you describe:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fullscreen-image

You can use as is or look into the code for guidance