# Variable is not taking the initial value of a variable in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am making a image viewer in reactjs. Actually I want when a user click on a rotate icon the image is rotate about 90 deg. All thing is going well but main problem is like when I click on any image and rotate it and close it and after that if I opens other it takes the previous rotation value but it must be zero as I initializes.

```
class GalleryModal extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            rotation: 0
          };
          this.rotate = this.rotate.bind(this);
          this.fullScreen = this.fullScreen.bind(this);
        }

        render() {
          const { rotation } = this.state;
          if (this.props.isOpen === false) {
            return null;
          }

          return (
            <div className="modal-overlay" name={this.props.name}>
              <div className="modal-body" id="image_container">

                <img
                  className="center_image"
                  id="image"
                  src={this.props.src}
                  style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)` }}
                />
                <a href="#" className="fullscreen button" onClick={this.fullScreen}>
                    <i className="fas fa-compress-arrows-alt"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" className="button" onClick={() => this.rotate()}>
                  <i className="fas fa-sync-alt" />
                </a>
                <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.props.onPrev}>
                  <i className="fas fa-angle-left" />
                </a>
                <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.props.onNext}>
                  <i className="fas fa-angle-right" />
                </a>
                <a
                  className="modal-close"
                  href="#"
                  onClick={this.props.onClick}
                >
                  <span className="fa fa-times" />
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
        rotate() {
          let newRotation = this.state.rotation + 90;
          if (newRotation >= 360) {
            newRotation = -360;
          }
          this.setState({
            rotation: newRotation
          });
        }

        fullScreen() {
          let elem = document.getElementById("image_container");
          if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            /* Firefox */
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            /* IE/Edge */
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
          }
        }
      }
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/r0h7gv62/1) This is what I tried so for but it is taking the previous value when I click another image or next/prev icon but `rotation` must be zero as I declared `rotation:0` . I doesn't know from where the rotation error is arrised as I think i did it correct.Can you please tell me what I am doing wrongand How to solve it????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, when you set the state having `rotation: 0`, you are modifying the state of the `Gallery` component; thus, when you open the model, `Gallery` Component has its own `this.state.rotation` variable set to `0`.

Instead, the rotation that is used to show the image is the one in `GalleryModal` Component, which is never set to `0` again.

A solution could be to pass the `this.state.rotation` variable from `Gallery` Component to `GalleryModal` Component.

There it is your fiddle fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/3hywna07/

Furthermore, at line 61, instead of writing:

`<a href="#" className="button" onClick={() => this.props.rotate()}>`

Just write:

`<a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.props.rotate}>`

Using arrow function inside the `render()` method should be avoided because it would led to the creation of the function each time the `render()` method is executed.

update link:- https://jsfiddle.net/c0qpk5wv/2/

Comment: when I clicking on the next and prev then the value of rotation must be again zero but in this it is taking the previous value. so I passed `this.setState({
            rotation: 0
          });` . Is there  any standard that use setState as minimum as we can?@matteo

Comment: Not sure I've understood what you meant: if you open the modal, rotation the image, than go to the next/previous image, you want the next/previous image to have rotation equal to 0?
If so,  at line 190 and 196 you need to change the `this.setState()` function so that it sets the rotation to `0`.. This way! `this.setState({ pointer: newPointer, rotation: 0 });`
I'm also editing  the JSFiddle just in case

Comment: Sorry, you edited your question right before my answer.. My comment do resolve your problem, but I don't understand what you mean with "Is there any standard that use setState as minimum as we can?"

Comment: Actually I mean that .... is there any restriction that use setState function as minimum as you can. In other word using of function setState more times is a good practice?@matteo

Comment: Well.. I think you could say that React is based on that function: every change on the UI should come from a change on the state (e.g. when you hover a button and its color became lighter, that should come from a change of the state, thus a setState call).
There is no "minimum" or "maximum", because you should call it every time you need a change (and, in your case, the rotation is totally a change, so it's good..  the fact that you go to the "next/previous" image is a change, so again it's good). You just be sure that you don't end up in a setState() loop otherwise your App will crash

Comment: thanks I understand what are you saying. And again thanks for the help buddy!!@matteo

Comment: can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778876/how-to-call-images-dynamically-in-ajax-using-react

Answer (score 0):

Matteo got it right. You could also let the modal itself keep the rotation and create a close function which will set rotation to 0 before calling the supplied close function. Gallery shouldn't be interested in the rotation as there is little value in keeping rotation between images.