# Why setState with callback function giving error : "TypeError: Cannot read property ‘files’ of null" while normal setState methods works just fine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a use case, can you help me understand at what point the callback `setState` method and normal `setState` method is getting executed, how does these two differs from execution point ?

```
handleselectedFile = event => {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return {

      selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
      loaded: 0,
      fileName: event.target.files[0].name
      };
    }
  })
};
```

When the event is triggered and method is called by child class and passes the event to parent class where above method is getting executed.

Above methods throws this error :

> “ TypeError: Cannot read property ‘files’ of null”

If I replace the above `setState` callback method with normal `setState` method, everything works just fine.

```
handleselectedFile = event => {
  this.setState({
    selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
    loaded: 0,
    fileName: event.target.files[0].name
  })
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, what’s causing this. I have searched a lot but couldn’t find anything relevant or maybe didn’t understood the solution.

Read this post, but unable to understand the problem with my situation : [When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Comment: Remove ‘return’ after the arrow on the first method. To understand why the error occurs, you need to understand how arrow functions work.

Comment: An arrow function usually looks like this: `params => returnValue` or this: `params => { /* function body */ }` You have `params => return { ... }` edit: ....aand you just inserted the missing braces

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry I have missed those braces during some console code deletion.

Comment: Glad it helped you

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes it was indeed very helpful, since I am new to react, I was not knowing that the synthetic object properties are getting nullified in seState callback function to increase performance. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Could be missing function square brackets

```
 handleselectedFile = event => {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => { <-- here
        return {

          selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
          loaded: 0,
          fileName: event.target.files[0].name
        };
      })
    };
```

Comment: Either this or removing `return` and adding parentheses around the object that is being returned from the arrow function should do the trick. So `(prevState, props) => ({ selectedFile... })`

Comment: Thanks, must have missed these during deleting some lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
  try this way     
  handleselectedFile = event => {
     this.setState({

      selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
      loaded: 0,
      fileName: event.target.files[0].name
    },(prevState, props) =>(console.log(prevState,props)))
  };
```