# Keydown is trigger before onChange on <input/>

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a requirement that after typing certain content in an  tag, pressing enter will do search function.

It running well normally like:

```
<input
  onChange={this.onInputChange}
  onKeyPress={this.onSearch}
/>

onInputChange = (e) => {
  console.log(2);
  this.setState({
    searchText: e.target.value
  }) 
}

onSearch = (e) => {
  console.log(1);
  if (e.which === 13) {
    search(this.state.searchText); // some search api ...
  }
}
```

But if user Enter really quickly, like 0.1s, the `this.state.searchText` is not get updated properly.

This is not just caused by `setState` is async method, but the `onKeyPress` is trigger before `onChange`.

is there any idea to deal with this issue?

Comment: you have to use callback in setstate function,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: Yes! But the `onKeyPress ` is called before `onInputChange `. So `onSearch` is triggered before `onInputChange `(setState). In this case setstate's callback will not work.

Comment: then try getting value by using ref

Comment: Have you tried ignoring Enter key in your handler `onInputChange`?

Comment: @blaz Sorry how to include Enter key in `onChange`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't really understand why you use two separate functions.

First of all, if you only use `searchText` for the two functions you could just do:

**HTML**

```html
<input
  onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} />
```

**JS**

```
onKeyPress = e => {
  if(e.which === 13) {
    // Send Query
    search(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

And even if you needed `searchText` somewhere else you could just do:

```
onKeyPress = e => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  if(e.which === 13) {
    // Send Query
    search(value);
  } else this.setState({searchText: value});
}
```

If I missed something please tell me ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input 
     ref={(input) => this.selectVal = input}
     onKeyPress={(e) => e.which === 13 ?this.onSearch():''}
    />
   onSearch = () => {
    console.log("value",this.selectVal.value);
   //  search(this.input.current.value); // some search api ...
   }
```

try this way

Comment: No... I think it still has the same problem. Basically, it has the same behavior as the example.

Comment: sorry, you're correct! Seems it should be work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
<input
  onChange={this.onInputChange}
  onKeyDown={this.onSearch}
/>

onInputChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    searchText: e.target.value
  }) 
}

onSearch = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    search(this.state.searchText); // some search api ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between mine?

Comment: Yeah there's a difference.The `KeyDown` event is triggered when the user presses a Key. while The `KeyPress` event is triggered when the user presses & releases a Key.

Comment: Incorrect at least as far as I know/read. `keypress` is triggered immediately. The difference is actually: `keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. `. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

Comment: yeah i was wrong actually `KeyUp` event is triggered when the user presses & releases a Key. but `KeyDown` event is fired first than `KeyPress` event and `KeyPress` event will not fired in all key pressed like when BackSpace key is pressed `KeyPress` event will not fire.