# I'm aware of async nature of setState, but I still don't quite understand my problem here

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form with a couple text inputs. One is required, one is not. I have a custom input that adds to a list every time the user hits enter and is required. When the user submits the form, I check that all required fields have a value.

If I have entered a value for all required fields and hit enter, I will get a message that the form is invalid. If I hit enter one or two more times, I will get a finally get a message that my form is valid.

When I console.log the values of prioritiesArrayValid, demoFieldTwoValid, and formValid on form submit, they will all be their default value of false until I hit enter a few times

I know my question is a common one. I know it has something to do with setState and async but I can't see the issue.

Below is the code that run when the user hits enter.

```
validateField(fieldName, value) {
    let fieldValidationErrors = this.state.formErrors;
    let prioritiesArrayValid = this.state.prioritiesArrayValid;
    let demoFieldTwoValid = this.state.demoFieldTwoValid;
    let prioritiesArray = this.state.prioritiesArray;
    let demoFieldTwo = this.state.demoFieldTwo;

    switch (fieldName) {
      case "prioritiesArray":
        prioritiesArrayValid = value.length > 0;

        fieldValidationErrors.prioritiesArray = prioritiesArrayValid
          ? ""
          : " is required";
        this.setState(
          {
            prioritiesArray: prioritiesArray,
            prioritiesArrayValid: prioritiesArrayValid
          },
          () => {
            return {
              prioritiesArray: value,
              prioritiesArrayValid: prioritiesArrayValid
            };
          }
        );
        break;
      case "demoFieldTwo":
        demoFieldTwoValid = value.length > 0;

        fieldValidationErrors.demoFieldTwo = demoFieldTwoValid
          ? ""
          : " is required";
        console.log("...demoFieldTwo", demoFieldTwo);
        this.setState(
          { demoFieldTwo: demoFieldTwo, demoFieldTwoValid: demoFieldTwoValid },
          () => {
            return {
              demoFieldTwo: value,
              demoFieldTwoValid: prioritiesArrayValid
            };
          }
        );

        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    this.setState(
      {
        formErrors: fieldValidationErrors
      },
      this.validateForm
    );
  }

  validateForm() {
    let formValid = this.state.formValid;
    this.setState({ formValid: formValid }, () => {
      return {
        formValid:
          this.state.prioritiesArrayValid && this.state.demoFieldTwoValid
      };
    });
    // console.log("this.state.formValid", this.state.formValid);
  }

  handleUserInput(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    localStorage.setItem(name, value);
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  validateFields() {
    document
      .getElementById("form")
      .querySelectorAll("[required]")
      .forEach(el => {
        this.validateField(el.name, el.value);
      });
  }

  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.validateFields();
    if (this.state.formValid) {
      console.log("FORM VALID");
    } else {
      console.log("this.state.formErrors", this.state.formErrors);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should use `callback`  correctly. I am sure that it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: I agree. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: `this.setState({},()=>{ *call function here* })`

Comment: I guess if it was a bear it would bite my head off, but I just don't see it. I am using callbacks (possibly incorrectly) all over the place. I'm really at a loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you had a sandbox or something of the sort, so we could see the full scope of what you are dealing with, not just the problem code.

From what I can gather, you're using state too much, and are expecting to receive the current state after setting it to determine if a form should be submitted or not. That's not really the ideal way you want to do this.

Your `validateFields()` call is synchronous, so validate each field without using state, then once you get all of your validations, *then* set state with whatever errors you have, and render based on that.

So kind of like this:

```
  /**
   *  Returns true if all fields validate, false if not.
   *
   *  @invokes this.setState() - state is set with whatever validation errors are found
   */
  validateFields() {
    const errors = [];

    const elems = document.querySelectorAll("#form [required]")
      .forEach(el => {
        const error = this.validateField(el.name, el.value);
        if (error) {
          errors.push(error);
        }
      });

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      this.setState({}); // <-- this should be your only set state? Set whatever you have to here, and let your app display your errors based on this.
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.validateFields()) {
      console.log("FORM VALID"); // Proceed to process the form!
    } else {
      console.log("this.state.formErrors", this.state.formErrors);
    }
  }
```

Like I said if you could provide a sandbox or something I can fork I could probably demonstrate better what I mean.

I hope this helps though!

Comment: That did help. Thank you!