# Unexpected user of comma operator no-sequences

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and I'm trying to do a call back function to keep my states in sync. I've done the below code which does work and keeps it in sync but I get the

> warning "Unexpected user of comma operator no-sequences"

```
handleInputChange = (value) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ amount: prevState.amount = parseInt(value, 0) }, this.handleCalculation()));
}
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: remove `this.handleCalculation()` from `this.setState`

Comment: First of all you are assigning to amount, `prevState.amount` and to `prevState.amout parseInt(value,))`. Why do you do this? 

What is value?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry i've new. I've been following tutorials that said I need to set the previous state and not mutate the current state directly. I call the code when and input field is changed, and when it is changed I need it to call the function handle calculation. When I put the handle calculation outside on a new line it doesnt keep my state in sync.

Comment: What are you doing here `prevState.amount = parseInt(value, 0)`?

Comment: Sorry I should of put my whole function,    ill edit my post

Comment: When I don't do parse int in updates my state to be a string instead of a int. Do i have it all completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set `amount` value. You can simply do this,

```
this.setState({ amount: parseInt(value)}, () => this.handleCalculation())
```

Another way is,

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
   ...prevState,
   amount: parseInt(value)
  }), () => this.handleCalculation()
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I could not use this.setState directly. I kept reading something about having to set the previous state? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the update, when should I use the prevState method compared to your first solution? I keep getting mixed messages online. Thanks

Comment: For more about setState refer this - https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60

Answer (score 1):

Basicly, your exmample is good. just take off the `()` from your callback :) because then you send instead of a function, you send the result of your computing function.

```
 this.setState(()=> ({ amount: parseInt(value, 0) }), this.handleCalculation);
```

Or send it as an arrow function to keep your scope.

```
this.setState({ amount: parseInt(value)}, () => this.handleCalculation())
```

Here is a good explenation about the state lifecycle
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Here is an example how to use is with callback once done:
[When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => ({ amount: parseInt(value, 0) }, this.handleCalculation));` - This is wrong.

Comment: You're right, The ")" is at the end, it should be after setting the object. :
this.setState(prevState => ({ amount: parseInt(value, 0) }), this.handleCalculation);