# How to deal with Unexpected use of comma operator no-sequences EsLINT warning

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint, reduce

I am getting an **eslint warning** for *unexpected use of comma*. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521321/unexpected-user-of-comma-operator-no-sequences) answer but it does not match my issue.

This is my code:

```
const reduced = _.map(_.keys(grouped), function(e) {
    return _.reduce(grouped[e], function(r, o) {
        return r.count += +o.amount, r
    }, {price: parseFloat(e), count: 0, amount: e.amount})
})
```

How do I get rid of the warning? Thank you very much.

Comment: Write the `r.count` assignment on its own line.

Comment: @Teemu what does that mean? Can you tell me how?

Comment: Thank you @Teemu, I didn't quite understand what the code did, that is a new syntax to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return` statement in the `.reduce` callback can be written as

```
  r.count += +o.amount;
  return r;
```

That does exactly the same thing, but it should make ESLint happy.