# Set multiple (interdependent) values on state at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine this code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "george",
    counter: 1
  };

  onClick() {
    this.setState({
      counter: 123,
      name: this.state.name + this.state.counter
    });


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="App"
        onClick={() => {
          this.onClick();
        }}
      >
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
        <h2>{this.state.counter}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I click on the `div` the output is:

```
george1
123
```

You can see that value of `state.name` is `george1`, **which contains value of `counter` which was current at the time `onClick` was called**. The `state.counter` value itself has fresh value though.

How is this explained? Because if I do this instead:

```
 onClick() {
    this.setState({
      counter: 123
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        name: this.state.name + this.state.counter
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Now output is

```
george123
123
```

It is same code basically but with different timing.
So what explains this behavior? **Why in the first case it has current value of `this.state.counter` (at the time of click) embedded in `this.state.name`?** And in the second case not?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-hugle-nexs2).

---

I know if I want to have old value of `counter` embedded in the `this.state.name`, and update `this.state.counter`, I could also do this:

```
 onClick() {
    this.setState({ // even safer to use functional setState here
        name: this.state.name + this.state.counter
    }, ()=>{
       this.setState({ // and here
         counter:123
       })
    });


  }
```

Is it safer than No1 approach (result is same)?

Comment: `setState` is async.  Using `setTimeout` is unreliable.  Try using callbacks.

Comment: Or maybe change the logic? You are using the same `counter` value. So, why don't you use it both places? `onClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => (
      {
        counter: 123,
        name: prevState.name + 123,
      }
    ));
  }`

Comment: When updating the state based on the current state it is generally considered best practice to use the [callback version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) to avoid updating the state based on stale values the have already been updated by a previous call to `setState`. In other words: Do not access `this.state` to update the state. Use `setState(currentState => (/*new state*/)`. Your handler is a closure over `this.state` so it uses a stale value to do the second update.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: Definitely need to be calling the callback form of `setState`.  Always a slightly different question, but always the same answer: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/1563833

Answer (score 0):

You are using the value of `counter` in both examples.  The difference is when `counter`s value changes.  In this example:

```
onClick() {
    this.setState({
      counter: 123,
      name: this.state.name + this.state.counter
    });
```

The name is `george1` because `this.state.counter` is still set as `1` (it hasn't updated yet).

In this example:

```
this.setState({
      counter: 123
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        name: this.state.name + this.state.counter
      });
    }, 1000);
```

You are first updating the value of `counter` so after the timeout `this.state.counter` is referring to the new value and as a result the `name` value will be `george123`.

As a side note if you need to refer to state in your `setState` functions you should use a callback so the correct value of state is guaranteed.

Comment: Well in that case yes it would be guaranteed because even though react batches state updates, and using timeouts, intervals, etc isn't reliable, both of the state values are updated in the same setState function, which react does not split up.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the comments and answers, using `setTimeout` is not so reliable. Most of the time you can change your logic and solve your problem. I'm not quite sure how the counter will change in your app but here is an example of how you can manage it. Using callback with `setState` you can reach the same `counter` and `name` value at the same time.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "george",
    counter: 1
  };

  onClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counter: prevState.counter + 1,
      name: `${prevState.name}${prevState.counter + 1}`
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.onClick()}>
        <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
        <h2>{this.state.counter}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```