# React Hook useState setter for prop fails

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I initialise `missingWeekDays` as an empty array `[]`. I create an array of strings `weekdays` and assign to `missingWeekDays`. But when I console out `weekdays` has content but `missingWeekDays` is still empty. Why is that?

Some suggested that `setMissingWeekDays` should have a callback like old `setState`. But I can't find any documentation on this callback... A link would be appreciated!

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Component: FC = () => {

    const initialStart = moment()
        .year(2018)
        .week(5)
        .startOf('isoWeek')

    const [missingWeekDays, setMissingWeekDays] = useState<string[]>([])
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(initialStart)

    useEffect(() => {
        const weekdays = createWeekdaysList(startDate.toDate())
        setMissingWeekDays(weekdays)
        console.log(missingWeekDays, weekdays)
    }, [startDate])

    return <CigarettesDetails onTimeChange={handleTimeChange} data={data} />
}

export default CigarettesDetailsContainer

const createWeekdaysList = (startDate: Date): string[] => {
    const weekdaysList: string[] = []

    let weekDay = 0
    while (weekDay < 7) {
        const date: string = moment(startDate)
            .clone()
            .add(weekDay, 'day')
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD')

        weekdaysList.push(date)
        weekDay += 1
    }

    return weekdaysList
}
```

Comment: Has a dup. `console.log` should be passed as a second argument inside `setMissingWeekdays`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Your setter from useState gets handled asynchronously. This results in your console log not having the updated data. This thread adds more color for you:

[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)