# Which approach is good to update State of the Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here's the working [example](https://codepen.io/chilupa/pen/LYYBJBx?editors=0010) in CodePen.

It has a button which toggles between `ON` and `OFF`

In [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), it used `prevState` and updated the value of state.

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
```

It also produces the same result when I use the below method.

```
    this.setState({isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn})
```

Could anyone suggest which one is good way and is recommended way to update the *State* the `Component`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Comment: @EmileBergeron No, it is not. The purpose of this question is which way is good to update the state using `setState` but _not_ when to use `setState` callback as mentioned in your link.

Comment: The duplicate target refer to both possible callback, [the _updater_ function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49207167/1218980), and the callback after it's updated.

Answer (score 3):

Because of to the asynchronous nature of `setState`, it is not advisable to use `this.state` to get the previous state within a `setState`. Instead, if you have to use the previous state, rely on the [updater function](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/40/How-to-use-a-setState-Updater-Function-with-a-Reducer-Pattern#:~:targetText=setState%20Updater%20Function,from%20any%20previous%20setState%20calls.) approach.

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>   https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: You don't need to use the `setState` callback, to update a variable. The callback is used to do things when the `state` has actually been updated.

Comment: You're correct, @leofalmeida. It's not the callback function, but the `updater` function. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you should do like you did in your first example.

It's rare that `prevState => ({isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn})` will yield a different result than that of `{isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn}`, but it can happen.

It's generally recommended to *always use the updater function whenever you are setting a new state that depends on the value of the old state*.

Here are two snippets that demonstrate what can happen:

#### Passing an object to `setState`

Here, despite increasing the counter twice with `setState` it only increments by 1 each time.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {counter: 0};
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }
  
  increment() {
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.state.counter}</h3>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

#### Passing an function to `setState`

Here, the counter increments correctly by 2.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {counter: 0};
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }
  
  increment() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}));
    this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.state.counter}</h3>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```