# React component not rendering response of Axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I have a form input that allows a user to input text and submit it.
Once the submit button is hit, I validate the input by checking if it's empty or longer than 120 characters.
I also pass the input to an API that checks the grammar and will fix it automatically.

Right now, my response from Axios is there (I can console.log it), but in my database and other places it is the uncorrected versions.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class CreateText extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            textInput: "",
        };

    }

    checkGrammar = async () => {
        let response = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https:/an-api-endpoint/',
            params: {
                apiKey: '',
                userId: '',
                content: this.state.textInput,
                format: 'json'
            }
        });
        const { data } = await response;
        // if I console log after this, I see it in my state as the correct version
        this.setState({
            textInput: data['corrected-content'] ? data['corrected-content'] : this.state.textInput
        });
    }


    handleInput = event => {
        this.setState({
            textInput: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.validateInput();
        if (this.state.textInput) { 
          // push to db and clear the text state
            this.setState({
                textInput: ""
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Failed handle submit');
        }

    }

    validateInput = () => {
        if (this.state.textInput !== "") {
            if (this.state.textInput.length < 120) {
                this.checkGrammar();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Failed validate input');
                return; // TODO: Error handling.
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="textInput"></label>
                    <input
                        id="textInput"
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.textInput}
                        onChange={this.handleInput}
                        placeholder="insert text"
                    />
                    <button className="textButton" type="submit">Submit Text</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CreateText;
```

I try to `setState` to textInput for the response using async/await, I tried other methods, but it seems when I hit the Submit/`handleSubmit`, it calls out to the API, but continues and submits, then gets the corrected input. I can see it on my text input afterwards which shouldn't happen since after submitting, the state text is cleared. It leads me to believe that it gets added, cleared, then axios data comes back and fills in the state (too late.)

Am I doing something blatantly wrong here? I'm confused about the axios promise and thought I could handle it with setState and async/await.

Thanks.

Comment: could you console.log and share the entire reponse? Without seeing that, I am assuming it's because your conditional is failing             ```textInput: data['corrected-content'] ? data['corrected-content'] : this.state.textInput``` because there is no data['corrected-content'] key on the reponse.

Comment: When I console.log data['corrected-content'] I see the correct thing, I also see it in my textInput form after submitting, but in the display component and DB it is the pre-fixed versions, which leads me to believe the async request or something slow. The response is fine, the timing is the problem I believe.

Comment: Looks like `validateInput` needs to be an async function awaiting the result of `checkGrammar`, and `handleSubmit` needs to be an async function awaiting the result of `validateInput`. The way you have it now, the line where you wrote `// push to db and clear the text state` is going to be executed before the grammar checking API call is finished, which means the wrong version is going to be pushed to the DB.

Comment: I see, is there a simpler way to do that instead of making everything async? Thanks for the insight @shawnyates

Comment: KostasX's answer below is probably the cleaner solution.

Comment: In order to understand the asynchronous race condition, try and placing a console log at the end of the checkGrammar() function, and also a console log right after the this.validateInput(); command inside the handleSubmit() function. You can test this on the codesandbox provided in my answer below, and specifically in the Original code section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the textInput conditional logic in the checkGrammar function like this to avoid asynchronous race conditions:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class CreateText extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            textInput: "",
        };

    }

    checkGrammar = async () => {
        let response = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https:/an-api-endpoint/',
            params: {
                apiKey: '',
                userId: '',
                content: this.state.textInput,
                format: 'json'
            }
        });
        const { data } = response;
        // if I console log after this, I see it in my state as the correct version
        const textInput = data['corrected-content'] ? data['corrected-content'] : this.state.textInput;
        if ( textInput ) { 
            // push to db and clear the text state
              this.setState({
                  textInput: ""
              });
          }
          else {
              console.log('Failed handle submit');
          }
  
    }


    handleInput = event => {
        this.setState({
            textInput: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.validateInput();
    }

    validateInput = () => {
        if (this.state.textInput !== "") {
            if (this.state.textInput.length < 120) {
                this.checkGrammar();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Failed validate input');
                return; // TODO: Error handling.
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="textInput"></label>
                    <input
                        id="textInput"
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.textInput}
                        onChange={this.handleInput}
                        placeholder="insert text"
                    />
                    <button className="textButton" type="submit">Submit Text</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CreateText;
```

**Suggestion:** You should definitely read more about how async functions (like `setState`) work, and try to understand async/await, since these kind of issues will come forth on a daily basis in JavaScript/React.

If you intend to work with React, you must understand the inner workings of the asynchronous `setState` method, and learn about the callback version of this method. A good starting point is this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback).

From the post, this is probably the most crucial point: "*`setState` works in an **asynchronous** way. That means after calling `setState` the `this.state` variable is **not immediately** changed. so if you want to perform an action immediately after setting state on a state variable and then return a result, a callback will be useful*"