# React: why we have callback in setState?

Tags: reactjs

Why do we have a callback in `setState`?

I am new to react and I am trying to understand but I am not able to understand fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
increasePrice = () => {
    this.setState({
        price: this.state.price + 1
    })
    this.props.getPriceData(this.state.price)
}
```

setstate is async process;its not updated 
example if you want to pass the data after modified you need to use callback as below

```
increasePrice = () => {
    this.setState({
        price: this.state.price + 1
    },()=>{
   this.props.getPriceData(this.state.price)
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

You should never modify the state object directly, but instead use the updater function provided by `setState()`:

```
// Bad
this.state.counter = this.state.counter + this.props.step;

// Good
this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {
    counter: state.counter + props.step
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is Asynchronous in nature. If you want to use the updated state just after setting it Callback of state is used.

Example-

```
setState(
  { name: "ABC" },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);
// => { name: "ABC" }
```

Read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback) post to know when to use it.