# setState isn't updating state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render components in `App.js` when a user logs in but when I `setState` in `App.js` (in order to render components), the state does not change

Firstly, I send the username and password from `login.js` to `App.js` here:

```
  loginSubmit= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

      if(this.state.username === "") {
        this.showValidationErr("username", "Username cannot be empty")
      } if (this.state.password === "") {
        this.showValidationErr("password", "Password cannot be empty")
      }


    const username = this.state.username
    this.props.login(username)
```

This is rendered in App.js here:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Lightning Talks!</h1>
          <Login login={this.login}/>
            {this.state.loggedIn ? <lightningTalkRender/> : null}
          <h3 className="form-header"> Submit your talk</h3>
        <Form postInApp={this.postInApp}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

It should call the login function in App.js (which is done because I console.log(username) and it is received):

```
 login = (username) => {
    console.log('username', username)
    console.log('username state', this.state.username)

    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
      username: username
    });
    console.log('username', username) // username typed in is logged
    console.log('username state', this.state.username) //username in state is empty

    console.log('logged in state', this.state.loggedIn) // logged-In is still false
  }
```

When this is done, logged-In should become true, which renders the `lightningTalkComponent` in `App.js` (see above also):

```
{this.state.loggedIn ? <lightningTalkRender/> : null}
```

The initial state in App.js is this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lightningTalks: [],
      username: "",
      loggedIn: false
    };
  }
```

Why isn't the state updating?

Full code is here:

```
import React from 'react';
import LightningTalk from './components/lightning-talk-component.js';
import Form from './components/form.js';
import Login from './components/login.js';
import './App.css'


// initialized state of App to hold an empty lightningTalks compoennt. componentDidMount sets its state depends
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lightningTalks: [],
      username: "",
      loggedIn: false
    };
  }

// componentDidMount is called and sets the state of the lightningTalks array in constructor(props)
  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/talks.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // sorts the data when component mounts from largest to smallest votes
      data.sort((a, b) => b.votes - a.votes)
      this.setState((state) => {
        return {
          lightningTalks: data
        };
      });
    });
  }

// sends a post request to the API
  postInApp = (titleDescription) => {
    const talk = {}
    talk.title = titleDescription.title
    talk.description = titleDescription.description
    talk.votes = 0

      fetch("http://localhost:4000/talks", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ "talk": talk })
        })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
         console.log(data);
      });
  }

  login = (username) => {
    console.log('username', username)
    console.log('username state', this.state.username)

    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
      username: username
    });
    console.log('username', username)
    console.log('username state', this.state.username)

    console.log('logged in state', this.state.loggedIn)
  }

// increments/decrements the votes in an object of lightningTalks
  incrementInApp = (id) => {
    // creates a new array based off current state of lightningTalks
    const nextLightningTalks = this.state.lightningTalks.map((currentLightningTalk) => {
      // if the id in the parameters equals the id of the current objects ID then place back into the array
      if (currentLightningTalk.id !== id) {
        return currentLightningTalk
      }
      // whatever remains (the one whose ID does match), += 1 votes of that object
        const nextLightningTalk = {...currentLightningTalk, votes: currentLightningTalk.votes + 1,
        };
    return nextLightningTalk
    })
    // sorts when number of votes increases
    nextLightningTalks.sort((a, b) => b.votes - a.votes)
// set new state of lightningTalks to equal the result of the new array above (the .map)
  this.setState({lightningTalks: nextLightningTalks})
  }

  decrementInApp = (id) => {
    const nextLightningTalks = this.state.lightningTalks.map((currentLightningTalk) => {
      if (currentLightningTalk.id !== id) {
        return currentLightningTalk
      }
        const nextLightningTalk = {...currentLightningTalk, votes: currentLightningTalk.votes - 1,
        };
    return nextLightningTalk
    })
     // sorts when number of votes decreases
    nextLightningTalks.sort((a, b) => b.votes - a.votes)

  this.setState({lightningTalks: nextLightningTalks})
  }

  lightningTalkRender(props) {
    return <div className="talks">
      {this.state.lightningTalks.votes}
        {this.state.lightningTalks.map((talk) => {
          return <LightningTalk lightningTalk={talk} incrementInApp={this.incrementInApp} decrementInApp={this.decrementInApp}/>
                })}
            </div>
  }

  // now the state of lightning talks depends on what is on the API. Below there is a loop(.map) which is set by componentDidMount
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Lightning Talks!</h1>
          <Login login={this.login}/>
            {this.state.loggedIn ? <lightningTalkRender/> : null}
          <h3 className="form-header"> Submit your talk</h3>
        <Form postInApp={this.postInApp}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;


import React from "react"
import './login.css';

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loginSubmit = this.loginSubmit.bind(this)
      this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        errors: [],
        pwdStrength: null
      }
  }

  showValidationErr (e, msg) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ( { errors: [...prevState.errors, { e, msg }] } ));
  }

  clearValidationErr (e) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newArr = [];
      for(let err of prevState.errors) {
        if(e !== err.e) {
          newArr.push(err);
        }
      }
      return {errors: newArr};
    })
  }

   onUsernameChange= (e) => {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.value })
    this.clearValidationErr("username");
   }

   onPasswordChange= (e) => {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
    this.clearValidationErr("password");
    // set state of password strength based on length. Render these as CSS below
    if (e.target.value.length <= 8) {
      this.setState({ pwdStrength: "pwd-weak"})
    } if (e.target.value.length > 8) {
      this.setState({ pwdStrength: "pwd-medium" })
    } if (e.target.value.length > 12) {
      this.setState({ pwdStrength: "pwd-strong" })
    }
  }

 // on submit, time is logged (new Date) and state of title and description is changed
   loginSubmit= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

      if(this.state.username === "") {
        this.showValidationErr("username", "Username cannot be empty")
      } if (this.state.password === "") {
        this.showValidationErr("password", "Password cannot be empty")
      }


    const username = this.state.username
    this.props.login(username)
    // call onSubmit in LightningTalk so that new talk is added from form

    // this.props.postInApp(usernamePassword)
   }
   render() {

    let usernameErr = null;
    let passwordErr = null;

    for(let err of this.state.errors) {
      if(err.e === "username") {
        usernameErr = err.msg
      } if (err.e === "password") {
        passwordErr = err.msg
      }
    }

    return (
      <form className="form-container">
        <label>
        <p className="form-title">Username:</p>
          <input className="input-username"
          placeholder="enter your username"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.onUsernameChange}
          />
          <small className = "danger-error"> { usernameErr ? usernameErr : "" }</small>
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
        <p className="form-description">Password:</p>
          <input className="input-password"
          placeholder="enter your password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
          type="password"
          />
          <small className="danger-error"> { passwordErr ? passwordErr : "" }</small>
          {this.state.password && <div className="password-state">
            <div
              className={"pwd " + (this.state.pwdStrength)}></div>
          </div>}
        {/*when the button is clicked, call the loginSubmit function above. E (event) is passed into loginSubmit function (above)*/}
        </label>
        <br />
        <button onClick={e => this.loginSubmit(e)}>Login</button>
      </form>
      );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async.If you want to see the state after setting it use a callback function

```
login = (username) => {
    console.log('username', username)
    console.log('username state', this.state.username)

    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
      username: username
    }, () => {
      console.log('username', username)
      console.log('username state', this.state.username)

      console.log('logged in state', this.state.loggedIn)        
    });
  }
```

Login function takes in a parameter, so the correct way to pass it as a prop is

```
<Login login={(username) => this.login(username)}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  How would I use this to get to the source of the problem?

Comment: Once you are sure you have the right values in your state you can further investigate your login method

Comment: I see. So I'm sure the right values are coming from the login method - it's just that the state isn't being updated. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It's still not working. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
login = (username) => {
  this.setState({
    loggedIn: true,
    username: username
  });
  console.log('username state', this.state.username)
  console.log('logged in state', this.state.loggedIn)
}
```

You expect the state to have the new values when you console log above, but that is not how state works in React. React batches state updates, so when you call `setState`, the state is not updated immediately. Inside the `login` function, `state.loggedIn` will always have the old value. You have to wait for a rerender before the value is changed.

Is your component rerendering? Or are you assuming that state is not updating because when you console log, the state has the old value?

Try putting a console log in the top of your render function, and see if the new state gets logged correctly there, as the component will rerender with the new state.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for this. When I console.log in render it does show. So that means I need to rerender the component, right?

Comment: I'm new to React and coding so not sure what to do

Comment: The component rerenders automatically when state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

hillybob991, As stated in ReactJS Docs. The setState() function is an Async Function and thus your code continues to your log statement, even before the setState is executed.

```
loginSubmit= (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

  if(this.state.username === "") {
    this.showValidationErr("username", "Username cannot be empty")
  } if (this.state.password === "") {
    this.showValidationErr("password", "Password cannot be empty")
  }


const username = this.state.username
this.props.login(username) //THIS LINE WOULD BE EXECUTED EVEN THOUGH YOUR SETSTATE IS NOT EXECUTED
```

So you are supposed to add a callback function in your code. The following code is exactly what you want.

```
login = (username) => {
console.log('username', username)
console.log('username state', this.state.username)

this.setState({
  loggedIn: true,
  username: username
}, () => {
  //WHATEVER YOU WANT TO BE EXECUTED AFTER SETTING STATE..
  //MAY BE YOUR CONSOLE LOG STATEMENT TOO
  const username = this.state.username
  this.props.login(username)

});
```

}

Comment: Thank you for this. So the problem is that the state isn't updating initially. How do I get the state to update? At the moment it doesn't

Comment: @hillybob991, the state is updating on the go, it is just that it has the async format!!
All you have to do is put your next piece of code as a callback function in the setState function itself!

Comment: Thank you, I understand just this piece of code is in the App.js file not the login component. Do I literally put this into the login.js file then? Sorry I'm new to coding and React so not sure!

Comment: @hillybob991, as I can see in the *FULL CODE IS HERE* part of your code. 
Your state is inside your login.js file!! So yeah this goes into your login.js file!
Where you can set the new State and then proceed further with this new state through the call back function.
And don't worry, we are here to help each other!

Comment: Thanks for this Ashutosh. Unfortunately it still isn't working. Have you got any other suggestions?

Comment: @hillybob991! Sorry buddy that is all I had.