# Why does this.setState work only after two submit events in react js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following is my `handleSubmit` function which is fired when the form full of questions is submitted. The trouble is, even if all 21 questions are answered, `filledAll` does not change to `true`. But when I click submit for the second time, `filledAll` is set to `true`.

```
handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let sum = 0;
        this.state.score.forEach(function(value, index){
            if (value !== undefined) {
                sum += Number(value);
            }
        });
        console.log(sum);

        if (this.state.score.length === 0) {
            this.setState({filledAll: false});
            console.log('Scroll to question 1')
            this.doScrolling("#question-1", 1000)
        } else {
            for (let i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
                console.log('Score of all 21 questions', this.state.score[i]);
                // wherever the score is undefined
                if (this.state.score[i] === undefined) {
                    console.log('if score is undefined, set filledAll to false.')
                    this.setState({filledAll: false});

                    console.log('Scroll to #question-' + i)
                    this.doScrolling("#question-" + i, 1000)
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    this.setState({filledAll: true});
                    console.log('else block', this.state.filledAll);
                    localStorage.setItem('total', sum)
                    // window.location.replace("/index");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using `filledAll` so I could know when all the questions are answered and to redirect to another page when it is `true`.

Comment: Is `this.state.score` a 0 indexed array?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous and batched so you may want to use its callback pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: @Jeremy I have defined it as `score: []` in the beginning and I am using it from index 1.

Comment: Are you using formik or any library for rendering the form?

Comment: I wouldn't use state for filledAll as this state doesn't reflects on the component render, just use it as a local variable inside the function, and if it is turned out true make the redirect

Comment: @JuanCarlosMigliavacca no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use state for `filledAll` as it shouldn't re-render the component.

I would suggest something like -

```js
handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let sum = 0;
        let filledAll = true;
        this.state.score.forEach(function(value, index){
            if (value !== undefined) {
                sum += Number(value);
            }
        });
        console.log(sum);

        if (this.state.score.length === 0) {
            console.log('Scroll to question 1')
            this.doScrolling("#question-1", 1000)
        } else {
            for (let i = 1; i <= 21 && filledAll; i++) {
                console.log('Score of all 21 questions', this.state.score[i]);
                // wherever the score is undefined
                if (this.state.score[i] === undefined) {
                    console.log('if score is undefined, set filledAll to false.')
                    filledAll = false;
                    console.log('Scroll to #question-' + i)
                    this.doScrolling("#question-" + i, 1000)
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (filledAll) {
          console.log('filled all');
          localStorage.setItem('total', sum)
          window.location.replace("/index");
        }
    }
```

Comment: add `filledAll = false;` inside the if block `if (this.state.score.length === 0)` and it works perfectly.

Comment: you can also live without the filledAll at all, if when ever you find a score that wasn't filled up you can just break out from the function `return;`. it will be more readable imo.

Answer (score 0):

this.setState is an asynchronous function. So updation of state will only happens eventually. In your case the code below the this.setState will run immediately after this.setState is invoked. By moving your code below this.setState to the call back of this.setState will do the work.

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let sum = 0;
    this.state.score.forEach(function(value, index){
        if (value !== undefined) {
            sum += Number(value);
        }
    });
    console.log(sum);

    if (this.state.score.length === 0) {
        this.setState({filledAll: false}, () => {
            console.log('Scroll to question 1')
            this.doScrolling("#question-1", 1000)
        });
    } else {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
            console.log('Score of all 21 questions', this.state.score[i]);
            // wherever the score is undefined
            if (this.state.score[i] === undefined) {
                console.log('if score is undefined, set filledAll to false.')
                this.setState({filledAll: false}, () => {
                    console.log('Scroll to #question-' + i)
                    this.doScrolling("#question-" + i, 1000)
                });
                break;
            }
            else {
                this.setState({filledAll: true}, () => {
                    console.log('else block', this.state.filledAll);
                    localStorage.setItem('total', sum)
                    // window.location.replace("/index");
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```