# Why I am not able to fetch query into my fetch url?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

I am working with 2 APIs, From 1st I am extracting the latitude and longitude, and then fetching into my 2nd API parameter to get weather JSON data.

In the form part, I have used a simple text input for entering city names, a date picker from which I can select dates for weather information and a button to submit.

What is the problem?

1. When I try to dynamically fetch query into my 2nd URL, for some reason it doesn't work, but when i try to render the same `this.state.lon` it correctly renders out the longitude to my page.
2. Previously, I thought this is happening because my state object is not updating, and I am calling the 2nd API without any value, but it is not the case.
3. I have even tried to call apicall1() at very last so everything happens first from the 1st then only I can call the 2nd one. But the same problem.
4. The 2nd API is getting bad request because the query parameter for `lon` and `lat` is empty

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    inputCity: "",
    lat: "",
    lon: "",
    date: new Date(),
    condition: "",
    minimumTemperature: "",
    maximumTemperature: "",
    calendar: ""
  };

  apicall() {
    let API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER = "my api";

    let city = this.state.inputCity;

    let corsCurrent = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER}&units=metric`;

    fetch(corsCurrent)
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        let lat = data.coord.lat;
        let lon = data.coord.lon;
        let condition = data.weather[0].main;
        let minimumTemperature = data.main.temp_min;
        let maximumTemperature = data.main.temp_max;
        this.setState({
          lat: lat,
          lon: lon,
          condition: condition,
          minimumTemperature: minimumTemperature,
          maximumTemperature: maximumTemperature
        });
      });
  }

  apicall1() {
    let API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER = "my api";
    let API_KEY_DARKSKY = "my api";

    let city = this.state.inputCity;
    let lat = this.state.lat;
    let lon = this.state.lon;
    let unix = this.state.calendar;

    let corsCurrent = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER}&units=metric`;
    let corsHistorical = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${API_KEY_DARKSKY}/${lat},${lon},1579257722?exclude=currently,flags,minutely,hourly`;
    fetch(corsHistorical)
      .then(results1 => {
        return results1.json();
      })
      .then(data1 => console.log(data1));
  }

  onChange = date => {
    this.setState({ date });
    console.log("changed");
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log("submit");
    e.preventDefault();

    this.apicall();

    let year = this.state.date.getFullYear();
    let month = this.state.date.getMonth() + 1;
    let date = this.state.date.getDate();

    let calendarr = year + "," + " " + month + "," + " " + date;
    this.setState({
      calendar: calendarr
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            onChange={e => this.setState({ inputCity: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter City Name"
            required
          />

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <DatePicker onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.date} />

        <p>{this.state.lat}</p>
        <p>{this.state.lon}</p>
        <p>{this.state.condition}</p>
        <p>{this.state.minimumTemperature}</p>
        <p>{this.state.maximumTemperature}</p>
        <p>{new Date(this.state.calendar).getTime()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: I would hide your API credentials

Comment: Agreed. Best to delete this question and ask again _without_ the key (anybody can see the history of edits).

Comment: @mbojko, there are more API credentials below :-)

Comment: Where are you calling the second api call? Anyway, your problem seems to be related to asyncronous calls. Try using promises or callbacks in your api calls, and remember that [setState is an asyncronous method too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback), so if you're using the state values just after updating them, you should use the callback from it.

Comment: Let me know if you need help with the code.

Comment: @ItaloAyres I am using promises everywhere, still i cannot pass the state values to my query

Comment: I have even tried calling the 2nd function at very end, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're missing the constructor for your component. I also added CORS to your fetches because your API request is going to another domain.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputCity: "",
      lat: "",
      lon: "",
      date: new Date(),
      condition: "",
      minimumTemperature: "",
      maximumTemperature: "",
      calendar: ""
    };
  }

  apicall() {
    let API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER = "my api";

    let city = this.state.inputCity;

    let corsCurrent = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER}&units=metric`;

    fetch(corsCurrent, { mode: "cors" })
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        let lat = data.coord.lat;
        let lon = data.coord.lon;
        let condition = data.weather[0].main;
        let minimumTemperature = data.main.temp_min;
        let maximumTemperature = data.main.temp_max;
        this.setState({
          lat: lat,
          lon: lon,
          condition: condition,
          minimumTemperature: minimumTemperature,
          maximumTemperature: maximumTemperature
        });
      });
  }

  apicall1() {
    let API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER = "my api";
    let API_KEY_DARKSKY = "my api";

    let city = this.state.inputCity;
    let lat = this.state.lat;
    let lon = this.state.lon;
    let unix = this.state.calendar;

    let corsCurrent = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${API_KEY_OPEN_WEATHER}&units=metric`;
    let corsHistorical = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${API_KEY_DARKSKY}/${lat},${lon},1579257722?exclude=currently,flags,minutely,hourly`;
    fetch(corsHistorical, { mode: "cors" })
      .then(results1 => {
        return results1.json();
      })
      .then(data1 => console.log(data1));
  }

  onChange = date => {
    this.setState({ date });
    console.log("changed");
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log("submit");
    e.preventDefault();

    this.apicall();

    let year = this.state.date.getFullYear();
    let month = this.state.date.getMonth() + 1;
    let date = this.state.date.getDate();

    let calendarr = year + "," + " " + month + "," + " " + date;
    this.setState({
      calendar: calendarr
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            onChange={e => this.setState({ inputCity: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter City Name"
            required
          />

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <DatePicker onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.date} />

        <p>{this.state.lat}</p>
        <p>{this.state.lon}</p>
        <p>{this.state.condition}</p>
        <p>{this.state.minimumTemperature}</p>
        <p>{this.state.maximumTemperature}</p>
        <p>{new Date(this.state.calendar).getTime()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: I tied this, still getting the same error, "poor formatted request". I am not able to pass lat and lon to my query

Comment: I fixed the CORS problem. I can't test the API credentials, but the request went through until reaching data.coord.lat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call 2nd API call after 1st one, and only in this order, you need `asynchronous` approach.

You can use `async` `await`.

Create async function and inside it use await for 1st call then call the 2nd one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function