# Calling setstate inside the callback of setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, setstate

Can I use setstate inside the callback function of the setstate
'''this.setstate(update,function(){this.setstate}.bind)''' 
is the above given code correct and will it work

Comment: yes, you can. .

Comment: Yes see : https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-setstate-callback-in-react

Comment: And will that thing give immediately effect to state ??

Comment: Does this explain your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: I'm  sorry it kind of doesn't actually  I know when to call it, but calling setstate  inside callback will it give immediate change to the state

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.setState({
 someState: newValue,
}, callback);
```

above code is using callback function in setState.

so you may write code like this.

```js
this.setState({
 someState: newValue,
}, () => {
 // some code you want
});
```