# Why does my react state not update correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Alright so I am building this CRUD app with a React driven U/I. I'm having an issue with my state updating. Below are the code snippets that are involved in the problem. I've tried figuring it out myself and think it's that my state is updating correctly but it gets sent to the server before the state can be updated and when my component remounts it gets the old state from the server and overwrites the new one. The server always gets a state that is n - 1 to the actual number of items. Also if you know any ways that i could improve, please let me know I feel like this is a lot of work to do just 3 tasks!

Thank you in advance.

My state

```
     this.state = {
            newItem:{},
            todos:[]
        }
```

The retrieval methods

```
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getTodos(this.props);
    }

    getTodos(props){
        axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER+`/${props.match.params.id}/todos`)
        .then(
            (res)=>{
                this.setState({todos:[...res.data]});
            }
        )
    }
```

My creation and update methods

```
    handleOnChange(e){
        this.setState({newItem:{title:e.target.value, complete:false}});
    }

    addNewItem(){
        this.setState({todos:[...this.state.todos, this.state.newItem]});
        this.updateTodoList(this.props);
    }

    updateTodoList(props){
        axios.put(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER+`/${props.match.params.id}/todo/add`, this.state.todos).then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }
```

Update: Oh snap! That is what I figured, you've fixed my bug!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Comment: @DarkQuaesar - the setState does not execute in same method you call it "addNewItem", you need to sent new todos right there and let state update on its own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `updateTodoList` before the state is already updated.

Do this:

```js
addNewItem(){
        this.setState({todos:[...this.state.todos, this.state.newItem]}, () => {
              this.updateTodoList(this.props);
        });
    }
```

`setState` has a callback that is invoked after state is already updated so is the place you can be sure it is, and call next fn.

Comment: Great answer! I would advise to first create a const with the new todos, and then call setState and this.updateTodoList, without the callback. Then both calls would be parallel, instead of one after another. This would be a slightly more performant setup.

Answer (score 0):

The state update is an asynchronous process.

> The issue here is your update API call is happening before the state
>   update.

To fix this issue use this syntax for state update.

```
addNewItem () {
  this.setState (
    {todos:[...this.state.todos, this.state.newItem]},
    () => {
    this.updateTodoList(this.props);
    }
  );           
}
```