# Updating state in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

setCount(count+1);
```

OR

2.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

setCount(count => count+1);
```

I am confused as to when should I be using the two ways of updating state in my component and what difference does it have? Thanks.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Comment: @hussain.codes No the link is about the class component's `component.setState()` method. But the OP's asking about `useState()` returned function. Passing callback to the two meanings very different things.

Comment: @hackape the concept is same, whether you are using functional or class Component, if your new state is dependent on the old state use functional update. that's the concept.

Comment: @hussain.codes Well. I just realized the `.setState(cb1, cb2)` method can accept two callbacks. `cb1` is the same concept. Before I always have the impression that its signature is `.setState(partialState, cb)`.

Comment: @hussain.codes No, this question **is not** about using callbacks *after* setting state, it is about the actual updating of state. Completely different concept.

Comment: @DrewReese yes you are right, this question is not about using callbacks after setting state, and i'm not saying that. please ready my previous comment carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use option 1 when the new state is independent of the previous state, like fetching data from a server and you are simply replacing current state.

Use option 2 when the next state *depends* on the current state, like incrementing a count.

BTW, option 2's pattern is called a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) since you pass it a pure function that takes the current state, mutates it, and returns the next state.

The following is a ***counting*** demo I've created to really show the difference between the two and why the distinction is important.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

/**
  * count +3 click handler using naive state updates.
  */
const clickHandler1 = () => {
  // assume count equals some number n
  setCount(count + 1); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
  setCount(count + 1); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
  setCount(count + 1); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
  // when processed the count will be n + 1
};

/**
  * count +3 click handler using functional state updates.
  */
const clickHandler2 = () => {
  // assume count equals some number n
  setCount(count => count + 1); // update queued, count === n + 0, count = prevCount + 1
  setCount(count => count + 1); // update queued, count === n + 1, count = prevCount + 1
  setCount(count => count + 1); // update queued, count === n + 2, count = prevCount + 1
  // now when processed each call uses the result of the previous update
  // count will be n + 1 + 1 + 1, or n + 3
};
```

[image: Edit react - bad and good state updates]