# Why this.state = wrong if this.setState won't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read in many places that I shouldn't use this.state, but this.setState instead; the problem is that it won't work for my code. What am I doing wrong?

**What I'm doing that works**

```
    submitForm = () => {
        this.state.isAuthenticated = true
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            userName: this.state.userName,
        });
        this.props.onLogIn(this.state.isAuthenticated, this.state.userName);
        this.props.history.push("/predict");
    };
```

**What doesn't work for some reason**

```
    submitForm = () => {
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            userName: this.state.userName,
        });
        this.props.onLogIn(this.state.isAuthenticated, this.state.userName);
        this.props.history.push("/predict");
    };
```

Comment: `this.setState` is asynchronous, the changes are not available instantly but after some time. If you want to read the same data you have just set you need to use the second `this.setState` argument. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous, so by the time you do `this.props.onLogIn`, the value in state has not updated yet. You need to do run those last couple lines in the callback of setState. See [When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous, so when you do this.props.onLogIn, the value in state has not updated without one render .check in your second argument of setState like this.

```
submitForm = () => {
    this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: true,
        userName: this.state.userName,
    }, () => {
        this.props.onLogIn(this.state.isAuthenticated, this.state.userName);
        this.props.history.push("/predict");
    });
};
```

Comment: If this does ans to your que than please consider this as marked .

Answer (score 1):

use the setState callback

```js
   submitForm = () => {
        this.setState((state) => ({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            userName: state.userName,
        }), () => {
            this.props.onLogIn(this.state.isAuthenticated, this.state.userName);
            this.props.history.push("/predict");
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain how this.setState is asynchronous. To address your question on why this.state doesn't work: this.state is only accessing the value of the state. You cannot set the state like you would set another variable. You need to use this.setState.

Also an alternate solution would be to simplify your code since *isAuthenticated* is known to be *true*:

```
submitForm = () => {
    this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: true,
    });
    this.props.onLogIn(true, this.state.userName);
    this.props.history.push("/predict");
};
```