# setState accept function vs object

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Lets say I have a state that I would like to update:

```
state = {
  description: "",
  notes: ""
}
```

Is there a difference if I update the state with just an object, if I do not need to use prevState?

```
this.setState({description: "Blue"});
```

vs

```
this.setState((prevState)=> ({description: "Blue"}));
```

Comment: Your second version should be `()=> ({description: "Blue"})`

Comment: Take a look at this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback)

Comment: To add to @NickParsons comment. You must include `() => ({description: "Blue"})` because your returning a object literal.

Comment: There is no difference. Second form of `this.setState` that takes a callback function, only exists to allow updating the state based on previous state.

Comment: Wait, now Im confused.Since I am not updating the function multiple times, I dont need to wait for anything to update for me to use a callback right? So I can just use this.setState({description: "Blue"});

Comment: if you don't need previous state to update the state, use `this.setState({description: "Blue"});`

Comment: @Yousaf Okay thank you. I got confused by the other answers.

Comment: @BrianBui `this.setState(nextState)` vs `this.setState((prevState, props) => nextState)` vs `this.setState(nextState, callbackCalledAfterStateIsSet)`

Answer (score 5):

I've created the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cn3mtn) to visualize the difference

```
/* When we doing this state gets update after the for loops runs so,
 this.state.count is same for each repeat so even if we expecting to 
count increase by 5 its actually increment by 1 */
updateCountByFive = () => {
  for (let a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  }
};

/* In this case by using callback to set the new state,
react is smart enough to pass the latest count value to the callback 
event if that new change not rendered */
updateCountByFiveCallback = () => {
  for (let a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + 1
      };
    });
  }
};
```

So it's a good practice to use callback version when you need to use current state to set the next state, since it will prevent some issues as above

This is what [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) says.

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

there is a nice [article here](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1)

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation! I understood why I should use a callback in I want to update something depending on the previous state. I was just curious if I could pass in an object and no call back if my updates are not dependent of the previous state.

Comment: Yup, That's Correct, I have updated the answer with react docs have a look on it, It says  `Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.`