# State Boolean Value Not Correct After OnChange is Called

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to flip a state's boolean value that is associated with a checkbox input each time the checkbox is clicked, but for some reason I am getting two different values at different points in the act of checking or unchecking the checkbox.

They both start out in the `true` state that is set in the constructor on component load, but then on the **first uncheck** of the input, the state correctly switches to `false` in `render()`, but in my `drawChart()` function it still recognizes the `true` state. When I **recheck** the input the `render()` correctly switches to `true` while the `drawChart()` function is now `false`. Is there something wrong with my function call?

For additional context, the `drawChart()` is used to trigger a D3.js chart and has an if/else statement that checks the state to see if a bar chart should appear or should be removed.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SleepQualityBarLineGraph extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.container = React.createRef();

        this.awakeChange = this.awakeChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            awakeBox: true
        };
    }

    awakeChange(event) {
        this.setState({awakeBox: !this.state.awakeBox});
        this.removePreviousChart();
        this.drawChart(this.props.data.count_sleep_disruptions)
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.data == this.props.data) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.removePreviousChart();
            this.drawChart(nextProps.data.count_sleep_disruptions);
            return false;
        }
    }

    removePreviousChart() {
        const chart = document.getElementById('bar-line-time-series-sleep-quality');
        while(chart.hasChildNodes()){
          chart.removeChild(chart.lastChild);
        }
    }

    drawChart(dataObj) {
        if(this.state.awakeBox){
            console.log("Checked in drawChart()")
            console.log(this.state.awakeBox)
        } else {
            console.log("Not Checked in drawChart()")
            console.log(this.state.awakeBox)
        }
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.awakeBox){
            console.log("checked! in render")
            console.log(this.state.awakeBox)
        } else {
            console.log("not checked! in render")
            console.log(this.state.awakeBox)
        }
        return (
            <div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-3 mb-5">
                <div className="bg-green-600 p-2 rounded-md mr-5">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox text-green-800" id="awakeBox" defaultChecked={this.state.awakeBox}
              onChange={this.awakeChange} />
                    <span className="ml-2 text-green-300">Awake</span>
                </div>
                <div className="grid-cols-1 mx-auto max-w-3xl bg-green-200">
                    <div ref={this.container} id="bar-line-time-series-sleep-quality"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default SleepQualityBarLineGraph;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because setState is asynchronous. Your drawChart() function will execute first before setState take effect. setState has a second parameter which is callback after the state successfully changed

```
awakeChange(event) {
    this.setState({awakeBox: !this.state.awakeBox} , function(){
       this.removePreviousChart();
       this.drawChart(this.props.data.count_sleep_disruptions)
    });
}
```

see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Makes a lot of sense!