# Callback after useState Hook in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to write something like this in a functional component. How do I do it?

```
setState({ allowScroll: false }, () => {
  setState({ messages: list }, () => {
    setState({ allowScroll: true });
  });
});
```

Comment: There is not callback after setState.  In my code I use global variable. I change it in function, variable: step1, step 2.. before return from function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
const [allowScroll, setAllowScroll] = useState(false);
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

// useEffect ?
setAllowScroll(false);
setMessages(list);
setAllowScroll(true);
```