# React useState array not able to set to empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I see the flavours of this question have been asked previously, but I don't appear to be able to use the answers to generate the effect I'm seeking. Completely accept that I might be missing the point somewhere...feel free to redirect me elsewhere if this is a well-understood/accepted situation.

Anyway, I'm using state to store an array of values, which needs to be updated via one or more API calls on a given action. As a precursor to calling the API, I want to reset the array to be empty, but aren't able to do it in the way I'd anticipated. Grateful for any explanation/suggestion/pointers.

The following pseudocode hopefully demonstrates what I'm trying to do, which is, when retrieveAllPreviousManuscripts is called it should:

- clear any previously loaded items
- call getManuscripts 'n' times and repopulate the piece of state

```
const [manuscriptsForReview, setManuscriptsForReview] = useState([]);

const getManuscripts = (offset, limit) => {
    setLoadingInProgress(true);
    let newManuscripts = [];
    doFetch(
        `${someAPI()}?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`,
    )
        .then((response) => parseResponseObject(response, addError, false))
        .then(handleErrorResponses)
        .then((data) => {
            newManuscripts = data.crowdsourcedManuscripts;
            setManuscriptsForReview([...manuscriptsForReview, ...newManuscripts]);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            //someErrorHandling
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoadingInProgress(false)
        });
};

const retrieveAllPreviousManuscripts = async () => {
    setManuscriptsForReview([]);
    // manuscriptsForReview.length = 0;
    let offset = 0;
    do {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        await getManuscripts(offset, numberToRetrievePerCall);
        offset += defaultPageSize;
    } while (offset < originalPageSize);
};
```

What I'm not understanding is why setManuscriptsForReview([]); is not having any effect when called from retrieveAllPreviousManuscripts.

If I replace it with manuscriptsForReview.length = 0; then everything works, but

- This feels like a hack!
- I'm reluctant to do it without understanding why the initial method doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: BTW since `getManuscripts` doesn't return a promise, instead of being called in sequence, all the requests will go out immediately and be fulfilled and processed in a quasi-random order. Add `return` statement before `doFetch(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @jonsharpe, the essence of that is what I needed.

Comment: Thanks also @mbojko, I see what you mean...had missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The changing state in ReactJs is an asynchronous action. Actually, it does work but the rest of the codes inside the body of `retrieveAllPreviousManuscripts` still have got the previous state of `manuscriptsForReview`. If you want to do anything after the update of the state you should use an `useEffect` trick to do this. But it will make your codes a little bit messy.

I recommend you make a custom hook that provides you the ability to pass a callback to the setter function. follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000280/6877799) and by using `useStateCallback` you can have a setter function with the ability to get callback argument.

Your codes will be like the following:

```js
const [manuscriptsForReview, setManuscriptsForReview] = useStateCallback([]);

~~~

const retrieveAllPreviousManuscripts = async () => {
    setManuscriptsForReview([], () => { // this is the callback function
        // and will work exactly after the update of the state
        let offset = 0;
        do {
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
           await getManuscripts(offset, numberToRetrievePerCall);
           offset += defaultPageSize;
        } while (offset < originalPageSize);
    });
};
```